# Providing RSS and Atom feeds? Do we need both or has RSS won?

Tags: rss, atom-feed

I want to provide some RSS feed(s) for my site. Is it worth providing Atom feeds? or is Atom the more common feed? Is there a winner?

BTW, this relates to programming because I'm required to program the feed which we will provide (or use some open source code, etc).

### Update

So far it looks like peeps are saying Atom should be the way to go if I need to only spend time supporting one? Anyone else agree with these thoughts (and hopefully backed up by some stats??)

### Possible Solution

While stumbling around the net for some RSS schema details, I was reading the [RSS Wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS_(file_format)), and they say

> As of January 2007[update], tracking
>   data from www.syndic8.com indicates
>   that the three main versions of RSS in
>   current use are 0.91, 1.0, and 2.0. Of
>   these, RSS 0.91 accounts for 13
>   percent of worldwide RSS usage and RSS
>   2.0 for 67 percent, while RSS 1.0 has a 17 percent share.[22] These figures,
>   however, do not include usage of the
>   rival web feed format Atom. As of
>   August 2008[update], the syndic8.com
>   website is indexing 546,069 total
>   feeds, of which 86,496 were some
>   dialect of Atom and 438,102 were some
>   dialect of RSS.[23]

This suggests that RSS is the dominant format over Atom.

So I might have answered the question myself.

Answer (score 16):

There are a few differences [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29#Atom_compared_to_RSS_2.0) which could be summed up :

- In Atom, the content can be specified (text, html) and can even be a binary (say, an audio track or a video) in base64 encoded form.
- Using the quite standard used XML date format (rfc3339).
- Handles content in different languages.
- Modularity

Also, the Atom file format is part of a greater scheme with is Atom Publication Protocol, which can be used not only to read but also to write.

Comment: Atom includes controls for editing a feed and single entries. AtomPub is useful for managing collections of feeds.

Answer (score 3):

RSS is a bit of a mess (see [this older article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/12/18/dive-into-xml.html) for a view of how bad it was six years ago, and realize it hasn't gotten any better in that time -- ***seven*** different mutually incompatible versions!), so if you've got a choice and only want to deal with one, you should really go with Atom...

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say either has or will win. Most readers support both, so there's no real push for one to take over the other.

But, offering both is probably just a waste of effort. Just pick one, whichever you prefer -- from your comments, I'm guessing RSS.