# Ruby Atom generator to use with merb

Tags: ruby, merb, atom-feed

I want to provide feed in my merb application. After reading wikipedia, [RSSvsAtom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347504/providing-rss-and-atom-feeds-do-we-need-both-or-has-rss-won) and seeing that StackOverflow uses it, I think I will use Atom. What library should I use? I have found [rAtom](http://ratom.rubyforge.org/) that looks quite good. Are there better alternatives? Or does merb has anything built in to help me?

**UPDATE:** maybe I should just do the news in plain html and use FeedBurner?

Comment: are you looking to parse Atom feeds or provide an Atom feed of something on your site?

Comment: I want to provide feed with news from the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for rAtom and for now, and it works really good - code is minimal and nice.

Answer (score 0):

While not Merb specific, you might consider using FeedTools - which is a Ruby Gem.

You'd do something like:

```
require 'feed_tools'
feed = FeedTools::Feed.open('http://url/feed')

feed.items.each do |item|
  puts item.title + "\n---\n" + item.description + "\n\n"
end
```

Anyway - check it out at http://sporkmonger.com/projects/feedtools

**NOTE:** This is for parsing ATOM feeds as I wasn't clear as to whether or not you were looking to provide an ATOM feed or parse others.